# Showcase View text gravity

Tags: android, textview, showcaseview

Is there any way to set the position of the Title and Message in a Showcase view? I see the library uses a function to find the best position but I want to override it.

Comment: Please elaborate what are you trying to say, show your code and then explain the issue you are getting.

Comment: updated op. Still haven't found a way to do this.

Comment: Submitted issue on Showcase View github. https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView/issues/113

Answer (score 8):

I just digged into the `ShowcaseView` source code and it seems there is no way built in to set the text position. So I added my own modification to the library. Here is the changes that I have made:

In class `ShowcaseView` added these fields:

```
private boolean hasManualPostion = false;
private int xPosition, yPosition, width;
```

Then in the `Builder` class which is inner class in `ShowcaseView` class, add these methods:

```
        public Builder hasManualPosition(boolean hasManualPosition) {
        showcaseView.hasManualPostion = hasManualPosition;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder xPostion(int xPostion) {
        showcaseView.xPosition = xPostion;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder yPostion(int yPostion) {
        showcaseView.yPosition = yPostion;
        return this;
    }
```

After that, add this method into the `TextDrawer` class:

```
public void setTestPostionManually(int xPosition, int yPosition) {
    mBestTextPosition[0] = xPosition;
    mBestTextPosition[1] = yPosition;
}
```

and at the end change `onPreDraw` method in `ShowcaseView` to look like this:

```
    @Override
public boolean onPreDraw() {
    boolean recalculatedCling = showcaseAreaCalculator.calculateShowcaseRect(showcaseX, showcaseY, showcaseDrawer);
    boolean recalculateText = recalculatedCling || hasAlteredText;
    if (recalculateText) {
        textDrawer.calculateTextPosition(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), this, shouldCentreText);
        if (hasManualPostion) {
            textDrawer.setTestPostionManually(xPosition, yPosition);
        }
    }
    hasAlteredText = false;
    return true;
}
```

Now you should create `ShowcaseView` like this:

```
sv = new ShowcaseView.Builder(this, true)
                .setTarget(target)
                .setContentTitle(R.string.showcase_main_title)
                .setContentText(R.string.showcase_main_message)
                .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme2)
                .setShowcaseEventListener(this)
                .hasManualPosition(true)
                .xPostion(0)
                .yPostion(240)
                .build();
```

---

Enjoy!

Comment: which version is this ? any idea how to make it work in legacy ?

Comment: The modification is for version 5.0.0

Comment: do you know of any way to bring the hand animation in 5.0.0?

Comment: you cannot pass this to onPreDraw...how do you write something like that without testing it and just give it to the asker

Comment: @Odaym maybe when he wrote the code there was no `CalculateTextOnPreDraw` class (which now contains `onPreDraw` method). Now, you just have to replace `this` with `ShowcaseView.this` and it will work perfectly.

Comment: that was great! that helped but how to center text in screen
i dont want to provide coordinates by hard code